# getGsmSignalStrength() return values that are out of range?

Tags: android, gsm, signal-strength

We have a requirement for our Android application has to retrieve gsm signal strength values that are greater than -51dBm.  However the [spec (section 8.5)](http://m10.home.xs4all.nl/mac/downloads/3GPP-27007-630.pdf) mentioned in the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html#getGsmSignalStrength%28%29) says that the valid return values of getGsmSignalStrength() are only between 0 and 31, mapping to -113dBm and -51dBm.  Has anyone seen Android return values greater than 31? If so doesn't that mean Android returns invalid signal strength values?

(99 doesn't count, that means "not known or not detectable")

Any other way of getting a higher reading?

Thanks

Comment: This is frustrating, as old Nokia hardware that we have lying around does report values as high as -10dBm.

Answer (score 1):

`getGsmSignalStrength()` actually returns the ASU (Active State Update) value. To get corresponding RSSI in dBm, do `RSSI = -113 + 2 * ASU`

Comment: And is it possible for ASU values to be crazy, like 35?  To give a result outside the range [-113, -51]

Comment: I don't think so. The docs say it should be in the range 0-31. And if ASU is not available at all it will return 99.